# Centering Animated Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have this jfiddle that I found that I modified a little bit to my liking. The problem is that I can not get the alignment correct. My goal is to have the five columns centered when they are all collapsed and have them centered when one is expanded.

http://jsfiddle.net/422MP/

```
#mainContainer
{
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 500px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.sidebar
{
    float: left;
    height: 300px;
    width: 20%;
    /* left: 565px;*/
    border: 2px red dashed;
    /*position: relative;i*/
    overflow: hidden;
    margin:0 0px 0 10px;

}
```

** EDIT ** To be a little clearer, it seems that when one div is expanded it is centered. When they are all closed, they are aligned toward the left.

Thanks!

Comment: Didn't understand about which alignment you are talking. Can you please be a bit more clear?

Comment: Sorry about that, edited for clarity. Let me know if you are still confused, thanks.

Comment: @user3363042 Right off, you should make all the sidebars the same class, e.g. "sidebar." IDs must be unique like you have them, but classes are meant to apply to multiple similar elements; these bars are a prime example. That way you can set things like height, width, etc. in a single class declaration in CSS as opposed to one for each.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, here is the updated jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/422MP/6/

Comment: @user3363042 Well, you would still need to set the colors of the blocks individually if you want them to be different, using their IDs. Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/422MP/7/

Comment: O I gotcha, excellent thanks! Can I align the divs in the that main container when they are collapsed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/422MP/34/

It's a lot easier when you have fixed widths for your elements, which is what I did. But the javascript is much cleaner as well.

To center the elements, you simply get rid of the `float: left` style, which will wreak havoc with center alignment, and set the `text-align` of the container to `center`.

Comment: Absolutely what I was looking for, Thanks!!

Comment: What do I need to include in the head for this to work? For some reason, this won't work for me once I put it in DreamWeaver.

Comment: You need to include jQuery. Familiarize yourself with the library at jquery.com. In the meantime, you can include this in your header: `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1):

All of the sidebars are float: left and the javascript is actually making them width: 10% when they are closed, which means that they only end up occupying the left half of the container. The div containing all of the sidebars is actually centered. You probably want to alter the JS to leave them at 20% and widen the containing div when one opens.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I'm having trouble making this happen. Do you know what I should change exactly in the js?